# Nix external software built/installed is not being found

Tags: nix, nixos

I've just started using the Nix package manager on OSX and I'm attempting to create my first package for the `pass` binary (https://www.passwordstore.org) - which is not available in the Nixpkgs repository.

I'm attempting to specify a runtime dependency (`getopt`), however this doesn't appear to be available when the binary is used.

This is my packages's default.nix:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
with pkgs;

let
version = "1.7.1";

in {
        pass = stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
                name = "pass-${version}";

                src = fetchurl {
                        url = "https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/snapshot/password-store-1.7.1.tar.xz";
                        sha256 = "0scqkpll2q8jhzcgcsh9kqz0gwdpvynivqjmmbzax2irjfaiklpn";
                };

                buildInputs = [ stdenv makeWrapper];

                installPhase = ''
                        make install PREFIX=$out/artifact

                        makeWrapper $out/artifact/bin/pass $out/bin/pass \
                        --set PATH ${stdenv.lib.makeBinPath [ getopt ]}
                        '';

                meta = {
                        homepage = "https://www.passwordstore.org";
                        description = "The standard unix password manager";
                        license = stdenv.lib.licenses.gpl2Plus;
                };
        };
}
```

I can successfully build this package (`nix-build --show-trace`) and install it (`nix-env -i ./result`).

Listing the runtime dependencies for my package shows `getopt` listed:

```
nix-store -qR $(which pass)

...
/nix/store/c5swmygzc0kmvpq6cfkvwm2yz1k57kqy-getopt-1.1.4
```

However when I come to use the binary (`pass init my-key`) I get the following error:

```
/nix/store/...-pass-1.7.1/artifact/bin/pass: line 302:
/usr/local/bin/getopt: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like password-store hardcodes some paths. You may need to patch those.

Comment: You should probably omit the .../artifact, because other parts of the ecosystem will assume binaries are in <storepath>/bin, not <storepath>/artifact/bin. (Probably not the cause of your problem though)

Comment: Fun fact: you can unquote URLs.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I have modified my package so that the wrapper is in `result/bin` - but the results are the same. When I look at the `pass` source I can't see any obvious hardcoded paths to `getopt`. When you suggest patching paths are you referring to using `packageOverrides` in a `config.nix` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `getopt` gets a special treatment. The [darwin.sh](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/src/platform/darwin.sh#n46) script looks for it using `brew` and `port` and falls back to `/usr/local`. That's why the (correct) wrapper has no effect.

So the solution seems to be, to make it look for `getopt` in `PATH`, which is provided by the wrapper script. You can probably make it as simple as `GETOPT=getopt` (which is similar to `openbsd.sh`)

For patching source code, see the [NixPkgs documentation](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-patch-phase)

Comment: Thanks Robert, I patched `src/platform/darwin.sh` applying the `GETOPT=getopt` substitution as you suggested, and it works perfectly. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After running `nix-build`, you should run `cat result/bin/pass` to look at your wrapper script and make sure it looks OK.  It should be a shell script that sets the PATH to include getopt and then calls `result/artifact/bin/pass`.

Then try running the wrapper script.  Note that the wrapper should be in `result/bin`, not `result/artifact/bin`.

Comment: Thanks David, I modified my package so that the wrapper is in `result/bin`. `result/bin/pass` sets the PATH:  `export PATH="/nix/store/..-getopt-1.1.4/bin"` and then calls: `exec -a "$0" "/nix/store/...-pass-1.7.1/bin/.pass-wrapped"  "${extraFlagsArray[@]}" "$@"`.

When I run the wrapper script I get the same error (as when I run the installed `pass` binary):

`/usr/local/bin/getopt: No such file or directory`

Comment: OK, the other thing you need to do is patch that program so it just calls whatever `getopt` is on the PATH, or calls the correct `getopt` from the Nix store with its full path.  It should not be looking in `/usr` because that goes against the goal of purity in Nix.

Comment: Thanks David, I patched `pass` as described in my comment to Robert. All working. Thanks for help!