# How to make a package that includes runtime dependencies and environment variables?

Tags: nix

The question may not be precise, but this is what I am trying to achieve:

The `puppeteer-core` NPM package requires a headless browser at runtime, and I found that I could use it with the latest Chromium in Nixpkgs. My current workflow:

1. I have overridden the `node2nix`-created `default.nix` with `override.nix` by adding Chromium to `buildInputs`:

   ```
   {pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {
       inherit system;
   }, system ? builtins.currentSystem}:
   let
     nodePackages = import ./default.nix {
       inherit pkgs system;
     };
   in
   nodePackages // {
     shell = nodePackages.shell.override {
       buildInputs = [ pkgs.chromium ];
     };
   }
   ```
2. Issue `nix-shell override.nix -A shell`.
3. `export CHROMIUM_PATH=$(which chromium)`
4. Setting up Chromium in the javascript files via `process.env.CHROMIUM_PATH`.

This works well, and the project can be shared easily with others by creating a tarball, but they would have to set up the environment manually as well, and I also don't like Chromium being included in the build dependencies. I could have just installed it globally with Nix, but the rest of the manual steps would still be there.

I read the manuals, and getting comfortable with the language, but haven't built a derivation or a package yet, therefore I'm sure I missing something obvious.

---

Some of the discussions I found on the topic:

- https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/automatic-runtime-dependencies.html
- [Runtime-only dependencies #1080](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/1080)
- https://discourse.nixos.org/t/handling-dynamic-runtime-dependencies/323

Comment: ["_the standard Nix approach for runtime dependencies is to wrap binaries in a nix-shell invocation._"](https://www.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/79j2bv/best_practice_for_setting_up_xmonad_on_nixos/dp2n9su)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Specifying Nix package runtime dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486270/specifying-nix-package-runtime-dependencies)?

Comment: See also Susan Potter's ["From Zero To Production (NixOS, Erlang)" slides](https://www.slideshare.net/mbbx6spp/from-zero-to-production-nixos-erlang-erlang-factory-sf-2016/46).

Comment: How did you do step 4? I'm trying to get puppeteer to work at all on NixOS

Comment: Managed to get it to work by setting `export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=$(which chromium)`

Comment: Sorry, haven't touched it in a year... Wanted to circle back to it this year, but if you figure it out, please post it, even if it's just a partial solution!

Comment: Sure! Heres how our team set it up: For non-NixOS users, they just run the node project that depends on puppeteer as they normally would. For NixOS users, you specify in your configuration.nix that you want to use the nixpkgs chromium, and you set the environment variable I mentioned above in their configuration.nix.